# Постановка тире | Русский язык

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Допустим есть предложение:
`Мой уровень английского - B2`.

Правильно ли здесь поставлено тире, нужно ли оно?

Comment: Нужно тире, оно ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым. В качестве сказуемого используется буквенное наименование уровня.